# Dynamic loading of images in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically get images from my images folder based on some information retrieved from the database. Gone through as many resources as I could but still unable to solve the problem. Here's my code:

```
import scimitar from "../../images/scimitar.png";
import defender from "../../images/defender.png";
import arrows from "../../images/arrows.png";
import cape from "../../images/cape.png";
import platebody from "../../images/platebody.png";

const ItemCard = ({ item }) => {


    return (
        <div>
            <p key={item.id}>ID: {item.id}</p>
            <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
            <p>{item.examine}</p>
            <p>
                <Link to={`/items/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</Link>
            </p>

            <img src={require(item.name)} alt={item.examine} />
        </div>
    )
}

const ItemList = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

    const populateItems = async () => {
        const data = await getItems();
        setItems(data);
    };

    useEffect(() => populateItems(), []);


    return (
        <div>
            {items &&
                items.map((item, index) => (
                    <ItemCard item={item} key={index} />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The value of `src` needs to be the path to your image as a string.  You shouldn't use `require` in there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: I'd also try to `console.log({data})` in `populateItems` to make sure `getItems()` is working properly.

Comment: @JosephCho Yup I was able to retrieve information back from the database, only field that was giving me trouble was the image unfortunately

Comment: @jmargolisvt so something like `<img src={`../../images/${item.name}.png`} alt={item.examine} />`  wouldn't work either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of issues going on. Using template literals like

```
<img src={`../../images/${item.name}.png`} alt={item.examine} />
```

won't work either. The reason why is `src` doesn't take in a path to picture, it looks at a url your website uses. You'll need to setup your React app to serve public images (e.g. make sure something like `localhost:1337/images/schimitar.png` works).

Only then can you reference it using

```
<img src={`/images/${item.name}.png` />
```

To serve static files in create-react-app check out [this link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder). If you have another setup you'll need to use something like `babel-plugin-file-loader` to serve public assets.

Comment: I was actually able to retrieve the image dynamically by placing the path of the image in a variable then inserting that variable into the src path of the image. 

`const imageItem = `/images/${item.name}.png`;`
`<img src={imageItem} alt={item.examine} />`

Comment: @JeremyChee nice job. Don't forget the reason it works is because you're already serving public files (e.g. `/images/schimitar.png`). Later on with different frameworks and codebases it'll be important to know. For example Next.js has a built in `/public` directory, but in Angular it's `/dist`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={item.name} alt={item.examine} />
```

Comment: a side note just for improvement: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this worked but I placed the path of the image in a variable before passing it to the src path of the image tag.

```
const ItemCard = ({ item }) => {
const imageItem = `/images/${item.name}.png`;

return (
    <div>
        <p key={item.id}>ID: {item.id}</p>
        <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.examine}</p>
        <span>Quantity: {item.quantity}</span>
        <p>
            <Link to={`/items/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</Link>
        </p>
        <img src={imageItem} alt={item.examine} />

    </div>
  )
}
export default ItemCard;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code if you are trying to get the image from a static path.

```
import image1 from 'images/image1.png';

<img src={image1} alt="image1" />
```

If you are trying to dynamically add the image then try the following code,

```
const imgName = "image1.png"

return (
    <div>
         { imgName && <img src={`images/${imgName}`} alt="imgName" /> }
    </div>
)
```